# Passing collections as data source to charts in vb.net 2015

Tags: vb.net, charts

I have the collection as a data source to a column chart for vb.net. The data in the collection is stored as in below format.

Task_no & "~" & Task_Type & "~" & no.of days open

sample data is

A123 & "~" & AAA & "~" & 5

I want to pass the file_no as x axis and no.of days as y axis to the chart as data source. how can we achieve this. I need a sample code on charting part too.

Many Thanks,

Comment: I suggest you Google Chart control in .net and follow the docs. Your sample data doesn't make sense to me. Is it a concatenated string? If so there are no numbers. Just a string. If you wish to separate this string look for String.Split. BTW A123 is not a number that can be plotted.

Comment: Here is the main chart control info [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart?view=netframework-4.7.2). And here is where you would put the [data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.series?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataVisualization_Charting_Chart_Series).